# Spring Boot JPA 2 databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using hibernate, spring boot, jpa
First DB is MS SQL. New requirement is to connect Oracle JDBC
It is multi module application. In main module  i have application-remote.yml file with DB credentials. Here it is

```
    spring:
      datasource:
        driver-class-name:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        url: ************
        username: *****
        password: *****
      secondDatasource:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: ***********
        username: ******
        password: ******
      jpa:
          hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming:
          physical-strategy:     org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      show-sql: true
      properties:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    jackson:
      date-format: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat
logging:
  config: classpath:logback-remote.xml
  file: /usr/share/tomcat/pqa.log
```

My Application config in module app, com.my.project

```
@Configuration
    @Import({
        ControllerConfig.class,
        PersistenceConfig.class
    })
    public class ApplicationConfig {
    }
```

My persistenceConfig in module persistence com.my.project

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
}
```

I have many entities in persistence com.my.project.entity
One of them is

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "locationSelection", schema = "dbo")
public class Location {
@Id
@Column(name = "timerName")
private String timerName;
@Column(name = "center")
private String center;
@Column(name = "station")
private String station;
@Column(name = "cell")
private String cell;
@Column(name = "place")
private String place;
}
```

Repository for it in Persistence, com.my.project.repository

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends         JpaRepository<Location, String> {}
```

And for 2nd databe in Persistence com.my.project.entityForIntegration

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "PQA_IN")
public class Pqa_In {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;

@Column(name = "UPD_USER")
private String upd_user;

@Column(name = "UPD_DATE")
private Timestamp upd_date;

@Column(name = "INS_USER")
private String ins_user;

@Column(name = "INS_DATE")
private Timestamp ins_date;
}
```

And repository in com.my.project.repositoryForIntegration

```
public interface Pqa_In_repository extends JpaRepository<Pqa_In,     Long> {
}
```

Now this is doesnt work. I have a lot of erros, with the classes and configs above the error is

> ***************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.my.project.services.impl.AnomaliesServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.my.project.repository.AnomaliesRepository' that could not be found.
>
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.my.project.repository.AnomaliesRepository' in your configuration.

I have read Spring documentation, baeldung, stackoverflow and other sites with guides and questions about multiple datasources, but i cant do nothing.
Please, provide me the correct solution to connect 2 DBs.

AnomaliesServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AnomaliesServiceImpl implements AnomaliesService {

    private AnomaliesRepository anomaliesRepository;
@Autowired
    public AnomaliesServiceImpl(AnomaliesRepository anomaliesRepository) {
        //
        this.anomaliesRepository = anomaliesRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntityDTO getAllAnomalies(int currentPageNumber, int pageSize) {
        Page<WeldMeasureProt> page = anomaliesRepository.findAllAnomalies(pageable);
        return convertToWeldMeasureProtDTO(page, currentPageNumber);
    }
```

AnomaliesRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AnomaliesRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WeldMeasureProt, WeldMeasurePointPrimaryKey> {
    @Query("from WeldMeasureProt wm where wm.detection<>0 " +
            "and wm.uirQStoppActCntValue=0 " +
            "and wm.monitorState=0 ")
    Page<WeldMeasureProt> findAllAnomalies(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code of `AnomaliesServiceImpl` and `AnomaliesRepository` .

Comment: @Arnaud the problem is not in this classes. It works fine without trying to connect second DB. The problem is in configuration

Comment: @Arnaud but added

Comment: Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.project.repository")`  to your main (spring-boot) class .

Comment: @Arnaud did not help